# i want name of the platform (facebook, twitter etc) from where visitor comes to our page in angular

Tags: angular6, angular7

Our web page is in Angular 6.
I will share my web page url in facebook, twitter etc. 
Now i want to determine from which source visitor has landed to our page.
for eg: if a facebook user clicks our web page link and redirects to our page, t hen there should some info which shows previous url (i.e. facebook url)

Answer (score 0):

You have to hope that there is a [http referer header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer). Its more likely to work if you make custom referrer links of your own, so say your URL on facebook being 'http://your-site.com?referrer=fb` or something like it.